# Heroku deploy - automatically upload images to Amazon S3

Tags: image, deployment, heroku

How can I make my images automatically uploaded to Amazon's S3 during deploying to Heroku?

I'm new to Heroku.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[asset_sync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) will do that for you.
Configure the initializer as mentioned in the documentation, and every call to assets:precompile will upload all your assets to S3.

You can then configure your app to use those instead of the local ones.